# How to repeat glitch that turns med vendors into gun vendors?

Tags: borderlands-3

In The Gateway of the Handsome Jackpot, the titular glitch happened, but it otherwise looked like a med vendor then I exited out of the vendor, and the glitch didn't repeat.

I used the ammo vendor to sell some stuff then went to look at the med vendor, when the glitch happened...

My computer is running on the 30 FPS cap, because it doesn't run the game that well...

Lowest resolution and resolution scalar of 50%.

[image: Only Meds and Ammo]

---

Glitch happened on the Ammo Vendor in Crimson Castle. I bought the Med Vendor's Item of the Day, if that's important.

Comment: Med and gun vendors are usually side by side, if you stand at the right angle, even if you're looking at one visually, you're interacting with the other one. Can you provide a screenshot of the machine where this happened?

Comment: @Sorean - The Glamourous Gateway has no gun vendors, only med and ammo... Got a picture.